# Move python code from Azure Devops repo to windows Azure VM

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops

We have a python application on a window azure VM that reads data from an API and loads the data into an onprem DB. The application works just fine and the code is source controlled in an Azure devops repo. The current deployment process is for someone to pull the main branch and copy the application from their local machine to c:\someapplication\ on the STAGE/PROD server. We would like to automate this process. There are a bunch of tutorials on how to do a build for API and Web applications which require your azure subscription and app name (which we dont have). My two questions are:

- is there a way to do a simple copy to the c:\someapplication folder from azure devops for this application
- if there is, would the copy solution be the best solution for this or should I consider something else?

Should i simply clone the main repo to each folder location above and then automate the git pull via the azure pipeline? Any advice or links would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you could try to use the [CopyFiles@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/copy-files-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml) task and set the local folder as shared folder, so that use it as TargetFolder. The target folder or UNC path that will contain the copied files.

YAML like:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder:$(Build.SourcesDirectory) # string. Source Folder. 
    Contents: '**' # string. Required. Contents. Default: **.
    TargetFolder: 'c:\\someapplication'  # string. Required. Target Folder.
```

Please check if it meets your requirements.